# The value 'core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter@12230cc5' is not a valid number

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am getting Following error while repeating map in visualForce.

source:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!stopLists}" var="stop">


<apex:repeat value="{!mapStop[stop.id]}" var="frightValue"> 

  <tr>


      <td > {!frightValue.Packaging_App__c}  </td>


      <td > {!frightValue.Quantity_App__c}  </td>


      <td > {!frightValue.Total_Weight_App__c} (lbs)</td>


      <td > {!frightValue.Length_App__c} L   {!frightValue.Width_App__c}W    {!frightValue.Height_App__c} H(in) </td>


      <td > {!frightValue.Freight_Class_App__c} </td>




      </tr>


 </apex:repeat>   
</apex:repeat>
```

==================================================

Error:(salesforce)

> The value 'core.apexpages.el.adapters.RuntimeTypeMetadataELAdapter@12230cc5' is not a valid number

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `var="stop"` attribute on the first repeat. For good measure also change `var="frightValue"`. I've seen [references](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AY6WIAW) where using system keywords as the vars caused issues.